# Visual Studio 2017 C++: Missing includes on cloned git repository

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created a new GIT repo with a Visual Studio 2017 C++ Console Project with custom linker settings and additional includes etc.

Everything works fine. But cloning this repo to my notebook gives me compile errors.

I added external include files and referenced them like this in the settings (C++/General/Addition Include Directories);

```
..\ExtIncludes\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

On my main computer this works fine. On the other one I get this error message:

> Cannot open include file: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp': No such file or
>   directory SFML-Engine d:\repos\engine\window.h    3

The files and folders have been cloned correctly. The whole project is the same as the one on my main computer.

Do you have any ideas how to find the error?!

`#include "../ExtIncludes/SFML/Graphics.cpp"`

This way the file get's found, but I get additional compile errors anyway, since the library needs the additional includes too...

Edit:
Okay, downloading the whole repository from VisualStudio.com as a zip file on my main computer produces the same issue...

Comment: Close all instances of VS then check that `git status` confirms that your original repository is clean. If that fails, you'll need to compare the original and the copy with the diff tool of your choice to find what's missing.

Comment: git status says nothing special, everything is up-to-date. I compared the project files using notepad++ and there are no differences. That's really weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Visual Studio does not open the project with the correct solution Configuration. I had to change the target platform from x64 to x86 and make sure that in the project properties the Platform was Win32 instead of x64.

Comment: Looks like you accidentally configured that include path for only one configuration, instead of all of them :)

Comment: Yeah :D Maybe I should fix it in the future, but as of now I only need win32 Debug :D